# Installing/compiling trouble with gfortran on High Sierra

Tags: macos, gcc, gfortran, binutils, macos-high-sierra

I'm having a lot of trouble compiling with gfortran on a new Mac mini with High Sierra installed.

I installed gcc with homebrew with no error messages. If I try to compile a basic hello world code or a piece of code which has been compiled and run with gfortran on my other computers successfully I get this error each time (full error from compiling `gfortran helloworld.f90 -o hw`).

```
FATAL:/opt/local/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!
```

I don't understand this error, but as I can get the same pieces of code compiling and running on Sierra I have to assume this is something not working between gfortran/gcc and High Sierra.

I would be really interested in knowing if anyone else is having the same problem or thinks if it's being caused by something else and knows how to fix it.

EDIT:

Compiling a basic hello world C code it works fine. No errors.

For `gcc -v`:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

For `gfortran -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0/7.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/7 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-7 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-checking=release --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 7.2.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-nls
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 7.2.0)
```

And for `as -v`:

```
Apple Inc version cctools-895, GNU assembler version 1.38
```

But this then gets hung up and has to be cancelled with ctrl+c.

I am running OS X 10.13.1 and installed gcc v7.2 using homebrew (installed both using standard instructions on homebrew webpages). Xcode is v9.1 and up to date. I work in a tcsh window, but the same errors occur when I test in bash.

Comment: The error is reported by `as`, part of GNU Binutils https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/ , not by gfortran. Please try to compile some very besic C code too and show us your exact details. Your commands for compilationa and the **complete** output with the error, the output of `as -v`,  `gcc -v` and `gfortran -v` output and any more details you can think of. Tell us exactly which version of the software you installed exactly from where.

Comment: (Sorry about all the coding problems in the comments... I'm new to the forum!)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Following something said on a different webpage mentioned, I've managed to get an earlier version of gfortran working.

I imported `gcc v6.4` via macports, whose gfortran apparently currently works on High Sierra.

It doesn't fix the issues of `gcc v7.2` and High Sierra, but it offers a temporary solution.